# Terraform : how to reference module in other modules?

Tags: terraform

How do I reference one module in other modules ?

For example if I have a module for S3 and one for KMS and I need to access the KMS arn in S3 how would I do it ?

I've tried adding at the start of S3 module the following

```
module "aws_kms_resource_module"{
  source = "../kms"
}
```

and then use it like `module.aws_kms_resource_module.arn`, but what I've noticed is that when running terraform plan I see that it creates two KMS resources instead of one.

Both modules are referenced in root module , the one that is the entrypoint .

Folder structure

```
 ./scripts/
   main.tf        <- entrypoint
   ./s3/main.tf    <- s3 module
   ./kms/main.tf   <- kms module
```

s3/main.tf

```
module "aws_kms_module" {
  source = "../kms"
  aws_kms_tags = var.aws_s3_bucket_tags
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "tf_s3_bucket" {
  bucket = var.aws_s3_bucket_name
  tags   = var.aws_s3_bucket_tags
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "tf_s3_bucket_encryption" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.tf_s3_bucket.id
  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {


      # I want to access  the aws_kms_module ARN 
      ###### kms_master_key_id = module.aws_kms_module.arn



      sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
    }
  }
}
```

kms/main.tf

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "tf_kms_key" {
  description             = "Key used to encrypt bucket objects."
  enable_key_rotation     = true
  tags                    = var.aws_kms_tags
}
```

./main.tf

```
module "aws_kms_resource_module"{
  source = "./modules/kms"
  aws_kms_tags = {
    Account_Id = local.account_id
    Region     = local.region_name
  }
}

module "aws_s3_resource_module" {
  depends_on = [
    module.aws_kms_resource_module
  ]
  source             = "./modules/s3"
  aws_s3_bucket_name = "${var.s3_bucket_name}-${local.account_id}"
  aws_s3_bucket_tags = {
    Account_Id = local.account_id
    Region     = local.region_name
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant code to the question. It's hard to conclude where the two instances of module are coming from.

Comment: Ok, so this does not work? If you want to call a module from the `s3.tf` you don't need to create it again with `module "aws_kms_resource_module"`.

Comment: Ok, and how can I call it ? I don't know how can I  call one module into another module. The above code works, but creates two KMS keys insted of one , I guess is because when I ask "module" it actually goes ahead and probably invokes the contents of the kms.tf file which will create a new resource. So what I want is to access the ARN of the KMS resource that was created into S3 module in "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration"

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 KMS keys created here because your code is calling the KMS module twice :

- One in the *main.tf*
- One in the *s3/main.tf* that is itself called by main.tf.

Visualize modules as "black boxes". You just provider them inputs (variables) and it will provide outputs (outputs and resources). It means when you call a module, it can itself call another module that can also call another submodule and so on. In the opposite, when you are writting modules, you want to write terraform code independantly on how it will called.

Now you need to ask yourself : "Who is responsible of creating the S3 KMS Keys ?" and basically have 3 answers to this question :

**1**. The s3 module is fully responsible of creating and managing the S3 KMS key. And this could be the code :

main.tf :

```
module "aws_s3_resource_module" {
  source             = "./modules/s3"
  aws_s3_bucket_name = "${var.s3_bucket_name}-${local.account_id}"
  aws_s3_bucket_tags = { /* Cut */  } 
}
```

s3/main.tf :

```
module "aws_kms_module" {
  source = "../kms"
  aws_kms_tags = var.aws_s3_bucket_tags
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "tf_s3_bucket" { 
  /* Cut */
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "tf_s3_bucket_encryption" {
  /* Cut */
      kms_master_key_id = module.aws_kms_module.key_arn
  /* Cut */
}
```

kms/main.tf

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "tf_kms_key" {
  /* Cut */
}

output "key_arn" {
  value = aws_kms_key.tf_kms_key.arn
}
```

**2**. S3 is only providing S3 buckets and doesn't manage KMS Keys, but needs a KMS key arn in input :

main.tf :

```
module "aws_kms_module" {
  source = "../kms"
  aws_kms_tags = var.aws_s3_bucket_tags
}

module "aws_s3_resource_module" {
  source             = "./modules/s3"
  kms_arn            = module.aws_kms_module.key_arn
  aws_s3_bucket_name = "${var.s3_bucket_name}-${local.account_id}"
  aws_s3_bucket_tags = { /* Cut */  } 
}
```

s3/main.tf :

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "tf_s3_bucket" { 
  /* Cut */
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "tf_s3_bucket_encryption" {
  /* Cut */
      kms_master_key_id = var.kms_arm
  /* Cut */
}
```

kms/main.tf : same as the example before

**3**. S3 is handling the KNS Key by default is no KMS Arn is provided in inputs. I wont put example here, but it would be done by adding a condition in the s3/main.tf.

Notice that no answer is the "good" one, it depends on your context, how you want to create code, how you will manage your infra and how you will maintain TF.

- Solution 1 makes your top level code more readable but you lose control (and it makes import a little bit more complicated).
- Solution 2 is the opposite.
- Solution 3 is a good choice for mixing both solutions bonus but it makes your code harder to maitain, because of algorithm and conditons.